# How do I run a python script from a file? (UNIX)

Tags: python, unix

Basically what I want to do is make a file called doPython and in this file I want to do the command:

```
python myFile.py data.txt
```

I've tried Googling and making a few scripts but I can't seem to get it to work. It says "No such file or directory when I try with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
python myFile.py data.txt
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/env python` says that your script is to be run with the Python interpreter. You just need to call `sh` or `bash`:

```
#!/bin/sh
python myFile.py data.txt
```

Comment: Ok, I changed it and then typed:
chmod -x doPython
but when I type doPython now I get "permission denied".